# Responder automáticamente sobrescribir fichero en Bash con gráficos

Tags: bash, script

Quiero actualizar mediante un script bash y de forma desatendida un sistema Ubuntu 20.04 pero me salta una actualización del paquete openssh, en la que me pregunta con la siguiente ventana que es lo que quiero hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debido a esto, me resulta imposible realizar la actualización 'unattended', tengo que darle a Enter aunque sea "a oscuras" para responder. ¿Como podría automatizar esto también?

El comando utilizado ha sido el siguiente `apt-get -q -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-all" upgrade > /dev/null 2>&1`. Al hacer el upgrade, se quedará la pantalla en negro y no avanzará, ya que aunque no lo muestre, sigue pidiéndote que hacer con la configuración del openssh. Si le das a Enter varias veces a oscuras (la segunda es por que te pide otra cosa del resolved.conf), termina correcto.

Es posible que en una instalación limpia en la que actualice automáticamente a la ultima versión 20.04.2, esto no pase. Pero partimos de la base de que este script se ejecutará en VPS's sin estar actualizados totalmente.

Para replicar el problema de forma visible, basta con instalar un Ubuntu 20.04.1 o un 20.04.2 sin estar totalmente actualizado y ejecutar un simple `apt update && apt upgrade`. De esa forma se podrá reproducir la captura y entender lo que quiero que realice automáticamente.

Comment: puedes pegar exactamente el codigo con que lo has probado y no te ha funcioando?

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que, si tienes que añadir información en tu pregunta, siempre puedes editarla (enlace Editar justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas). Con eso, la info relevante de tu pregunta no se pierde entre los comentarios.

Comment: Actualizada la pregunta. (Gracias Alfabravo)

Answer (score 1):

Dos apuntes:

- comillas mal puestas
- `--force-all` no sale en el manual `dpkg`.

#### solución

```
apt-get update
apt-get --yes --force-yes -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade
```

#### detalle

Realmente quien trata en detalle la instalación de los paquetes es `dpkg`. Es por eso que debe pasarse como configuracion especifica `-o` en `apt`.

Con eso comando les estas diciendo que en caso de que se haya modificado un fichero de configuracion `confile` primero haga lo que haría por defecto `--force-confdef`, y en caso de no estar definido que deje el fichero viejo `--force-confold`.

Para más información puedes consultar el [`man dpkg`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg/dpkg.1.es.html) y [`man apt-get`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

Comment: Interesantes los apuntes, ya veo que lo estaba haciendo mal. Sin embargo sigue sin seguir adelante con la configuración nueva del fichero /etc/ssh/sshd_config aunque si pasa la segunda pregunta sobre el fichero /etc/systemd/resolved.conf. Se sigue quedando "atascado" en la imagen que adjunto en la pregunta. He estado mirando la ayuda y creo que lo que pretendo hacer no es posible me parece a mi...